# Function calls are not supported in decorator

Tags: angular, decorator, aot

I am trying to build app with `-aot` option (`ng build -aot`). I’ve got the following error:

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'MyComponent'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'classLogger' was called in 'cLog'
    'cLog' calls 'classLogger'.
```

However I need this calls and I don’t have an idea how I am supposed to change the code to make it work.

```
export function classLogger(_classOptions?) {
   const myLogger = new MyLogger();
   myLogger.options = Object.assign({}, defaultClassOptions, _classOptions);

   return myLogger.loggerCB;
}

// export function clog(options = defaultClassOptions): Function {
export function cLog(options?): Function {
   return loggingEnabled ? classLogger(options) : emptyClassDecorator();
}
```

P.S. Class decorator takes options which must be transferred to decorator patch callback.

Comment: looks like @angular/cli 1.6.8 solved the problem...

Answer (score -1):

I also came across with this problem. In my situation I want to override BusyConfig params. App works properly with `ng serve` but when I want to build app for production `Function calls are not supported in decorators but ...` exception occurs.

My solution is following: 
`ng build --prod --aot=false`

> The Angular Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compiler converts your Angular HTML
>   and TypeScript code into efficient JavaScript code during the build
>   phase before the browser downloads and runs that code.

`ng build --prod` is same as `ng build --prod --aot`

Comment: Your solution does not solve anything. I came across the problem especially wanting to use AOT. AOT is essential for production.